# How can I move /var to another harddrive?

Tags: mount, fstab, ssd, mountpoint

I've put a new SSD as `/dev/sda`, the old HD as `/dev/sdb`.  And done a fresh installation as one partition on `/dev/sda1`.

The main quirk in my set-up is that I don't want to repartition the old HD, since it's got lots of data on it.

Since I had a swap partition on the HD before, I've put that into fstab.  I've also mounted the HD.  And `/tmp` (and `/tmp/var`) are in tmpfs.

But, how can I go about moving /var to the HD?  I can junk the old one (currently sitting under root at `/dev/sdb5`, and `/mnt/hd`).

Doing a simple `ln -s /mnt/hd/var /var` doesn't seem to work.  Is this something I need to do with `mount -o bind`?   I'm asking because the "attempt, fail, recover" cycle time is pretty long.

Comment: Why do you want to preserve the old var?  Or if not preserve... why have /var on your HDD?  It's written to pretty frequently, I'd much rather have it on my SSD.  I don't think having it on a separate drive (from `/`) makes up for the HDD speed and latency hit.

Comment: But I've seen many recommendations on the net to keep /var off the SSD, simply because it gets written to a lot...  And I'm trying to avoid excessive wear on the SSD.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and easy way would be to edit your /etc/fstab file and add an entry similar to the one that you should see for the / partition and just put the necessary pointers such as the fs type, ext4 and point it to /dev/sdb5. Reboot and it should work. I would mount it to a temporary mount point and recursively copy or rsync it to that filesystem to ensure that you do not loose any data first.

Comment: But doesn't mounting /dev/sdb5 as /var declare the whole partition as /var?  I have other directories on that partition (such as my old /home/...)

Comment: Yes, so you would need to do some cleanup so that /var only has data specific to /var.